# How to create complex query to Elasticsearch with OR logic using Spring Data Elasticsearch?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I'm looking for best approach to make complex query to Elasticsearch with OR logic from java.

I really need something like **((A and B) or (C and D) or (E and F and G))**.

Now I using ElasticsearchTemplate and `org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.query.Criteria.class`.

But I cannot implement OR logic in one query and I have to do separate requests to Elasticsearch:

- one for (A and B),
- one for (C and D), and so on...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible, there is a [Jira issue](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAES-706) for that. This is one of the issues that I'd like to fix as soon as possible, but at the moment we are working on getting the 4.0 release ready.

Alas this needs a whole rewrite of the `Criteria` class to have this functionality, but of course we must not break the existing functionality. So this is not something that can be done with a quick fix (otherwise I'd fixed it already last december).

Answer (score 6):

You can model OR and AND Queries with boolean Queries:

In your example it is:

`boolQuery().should(boolQuery().must(A).must(B))
            .should(boolQuery().must(C).must(D))
            .should(boolQuery().must(E).must(F).must(G));`

Comment: Thank you. That and the previous message put me in the right path. I just could not get myself to believe there was no way to do nested conditions with Criteria. A real oversight, IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

The AND in elasticSearch is Must the OR is Should, and you got too the MustNot for AND NOT

You can concat them with a bool query, like this example https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

Answer (score 0):

Update: Sorry i had wrong logic, As AND operator has preference over OR operator, simply removing bracket will work

I think the following logic will work

> ((A and B) or (C and D) or (E and F and G)) = A and B or C and D or E
>   and F and G